# Android certificate issue

Tags: java, android, certificate, google-play, keytool

If I lost the original certificate.keystore file created with keytool, but have the exact terminal output and all the stuff I entered to make it, is that enough to be able to create a new certificate that the android market publish site will accept without saying that the new apk must be signed with the same certificate?

Comment: Try this: create two new keys using duplicate information. I believe you'll find they are not identical, but either way, you'll be answering your question.

Comment: @mah so basically if I don't have the *original* certificate.keystore file there's no way to update my android app, correct?

Comment: @mah nope, a quick md5 showed that they're different. :-/

Comment: This might sound stupid, but have you tried contacting google about this? I'm thinking of making a paid app and this story terrifies me.

Comment: @Steven yes, we are certainly going to contact Google. Just wanted to see if we can resolve it ourselves first. If this story terrifies you, learn from my mistake: *backup everything*, and then *backup those backups*, preferably to an off-site location. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a MAJOR flaw in the google android market. unlike apple where you can request your certificate with your apple developer account, google has no such service yet. If you loose your certificate, thats it. You will be unable to publish an updated version of your app for people to download.

Best thing to do is let your userbase know there is a new version of the app out with changes that made it impossible to update normally, and they need to uninstall the old version and download the new version, unpublish the old version from the app store and publish the new one. (its a bit of a white lie, but people wont cry too much, and its a lot better than saying you lost the certificate, most users wont even know what you are on about)

Then keep your certificate duplicated for backups and keep it SAFE!!! Email it to yourself, put it on a unnamed flashdrive (incase it gets stolen people wont know what the certificates for). Gmail is good because its easy to retrieve mail from months ago with keywords. Burn it on a CD and put it in your medicine cabinet if you have to.

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: Yes, it is a major flaw, I agree. When I made it, i was sure to save the info I used to make it, but not the certificate itself. The issue with republishing is that it's a paid app, and users will complain beyond belief if they have to pay again, which is what I'm worried about.

Comment: *AND*, there's no way to give out an app for free (like promo codes with the apple app store), so I couldn't just give existing users a free license. Any ideas?]

Comment: ugh thats a bit hairy. ive never released a paid app so i wont be much help here. you have a list of what accounts have paid right? you might be able to grant those accounts your new app manually or with a script (depending on how many users you have) so when they go to download it, it just says install instead of purchase?

Comment: i think ive seen users being given refunds manually by developers. this might cost you a bucketload, but if you refund all your users ,and direct them yo purchase the new app and they know exactly whats going on (ie: they know they have a refund for the old one automatically, so they can purchase the new one) it might work out, but you would loose any profit if people dont want the new one/dont use the old one anymore. To avoid this you could ask if users want the new one to email you and youll refund them the old one so they can purchase the new one. harder on their part but less profit lost

Comment: Wow. I'm not sure if I can grant access to a user to one of my apps, the developer console is extremely limited. Can you even refund orders from several months ago that have already been paid out? And it seems like with Apple (not sure about android), but when you refund, Apple still keeps their 30%, so you actually *lose* money when refunds occur, as Apple wants their 30% and the user still wants their full 99 cents.

Comment: rock and a hard place man, last idea i have is to ask paid users to forward you their receipt that google sent them when they purchased your app, and then when they buy it again, refund those users instantly before you get paid out of the market. itd take some work, and hassle on the users side of things though. I also dont know if refunding them would disable the app on their account. probably.
:(

all the best of luck for this situation, hope you can smooth it over well

Comment: Thanks for your help and encouragement, would it be potentially bad if I have users send me their receipt (or I just look it up), and if they bought the previous version, just send them an apk? I don't have the market DRM on it anyways, so already someone could just upload the apk to some site, so I don't know if it would matter too much. Marked as answer for all your suggestions.

Comment: Last comment i swear haha, this is turning into a discussion. 1st problem with that is the user would have to have the install from unknown sources checkbox on for them to install it. probably isnt much of a problem, alot of users have it checked (anyone who develops, any external market users who use amazon or such) but it might miff some people. step by step instructions on checking it if they dont have it checked already isnt too hard though. 2nd problem with that idea is that future updates wont automatically get rolled out for them, as they haven't installed through android market.

Comment: Nope, I get the last comment! :-) Google replied, and there is no workaround for losing the certificate, and in order to make an app free for someone, you do have to refund. You're right about them having to have non-market sources enabled, but - if I uploaded the new app to the market, downloaded it to my device and backed up that apk - would they be able to isntall it without having to have non-market sources enabled, since it would be signed with the market stuff?

Comment: im not sure, try it by downloading your current app, and try installing it outside of the market, as its signed with the market stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the generated certificate and the private key will be the same.