# How to extend expire date of my Key generated by KeyTool on Android?

Tags: android, key, keytool

I have a problem with my key generated by keytool. It expires in a few months so I have two questions:

1. How to extend that date? Should I generate another one and sign my app with the new one?
2. What will be with this application in GooglePlay after the key is expired? Should it be deleted? It will never update anymore? It has over 5 million downloads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073717/android-certificate-issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781256/android-certificate-is-expired